calculate$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}J_n(\omega)^2e^{jn\psi}$
I am wondering how to calculate the following expression:
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}J_n(\omega)^2e^{jn\psi}$$
I have tried to use the Jacobi-Anger Expansion, also the equation below:
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}J_n(x)^2=1$$
but it doesn't work.
I am curious that Does this problem have an analytical solution, if so, how to calculate it?

Since this is a complex valued function and the projection sum is as well a complex valued function this is with respect to the squaring operation incomplete. This kind of square formulation for complex valued function is sluggish and can be considered incomplete. Better to formulated absolute square or if this is intended more complicated the meaning of the squaring.

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}J_n(\omega)^2e^{in\psi}=J_0\left(2\omega\sin\frac\psi2\right)$$ (see intermediate results here or here).

Thank you! It helps me a lot!

Hello, I find these topics quite fascinating and am keen to expand my understanding in this field. Would you be able to recommend some relevant literature or websites? I would greatly appreciate your guidance
